# Variable in a form won't keep its value after being used in the call to another form

Tags: vba, ms-access, variables

I have a form with a variable in it called "VigilTable."  This variable gets its value from the calling string OpenArgs property.

Among other things, I use this variable in the call string when opening other forms.

But it only works the first call.

MsgBox VigilTable before the call will always show "Spring2022" or whatever on the first call but always comes up blank on succeeding calls (and I get "invalid use of NULL" when the called form attempts to extract the value from OpenArgs).  The variable is dimmed as String in the General section of the form's VBA code.

So what's happening here?  And can I fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: You could record the value of the variable in a cell in a backend, hidden worksheet, and recall it when it's time to call it in the next form. That's how I've dealt with this issue before. You would have two separate subs for each form, I think; another way is that you can pass the value to the sub where you need it and initiate the second from by clicking a button on the first.

Comment: If you declare the variable in discussion on top of a **Standard module** (in the declarations area), it should be updated and used by all the other modules/forms/sheet modules. `Public VigilTable as string`. If you insist to use it in a form, declare it in the same way (in the form code module declarations area), but use it as `UserForm.VigilTable `... It may receive values even if the form is not shown. `UserForm.VigilTable = "test variable"`.

Comment: Public variables are possible, but not among the best programming practices...

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so you delcared a variable at the form level (code module) for that given form.

and we assume that say on form load, you set this varible to the OpenArgs of the form on form load.

So, say like this:

```
  Option Compare Database
  Option Explicit
  
  Public MyTest     As String
  
  
  
  Private Sub Form_Load()
  
      MyTest = Me.OpenArgs
  
  End Sub
```

Well, I can't say having a variable helps all that much, since any and all code in that form can use me.OpenArgs.

but, do keep in mind the following:

ONLY VBA code in the form can freely use that variable. It is NOT global to the applcation, but only code in the given form.

However, other VBA code outside of the form can in fact use this variable. But ONLY as long as the form is open.

So, in the forms code, you can go;

```
MsgBox MyTest
```

But, for VBA outside of the form, then you can get use of the value like this:

```
Msgbox forms!cityTest.MyTest
```

However, do keep in mind that any un-handled error will (and does) blow out all global and local variables. So, maybe you have a un-handled error.

Of course if you compile (and deploy) a compiled accDB->accDE, then any errors does NOT re-set these local and global variables.

but, for the most part, that "value" should persist ONLY as long as the form is open, and if you close that form, then of course the values and variables for that form will go out of scope (not exist).

Now, you could consider moving the variable declare to a standard code module, and then it would be really global in nature, but for the most part, such code is not recommended, since it hard to debug, and such code is not very modular, or even easy to maintain over time.

So, this suggests that some error in VBA code is occurring, and when that does occur, then all such variables are re-set (but, the noted exception is if you compile down to an accDE - and any and all variables will thus persist - and even persist their values when VBA errors are encountered.

Comment: I use a variable rather than referring to OpenArgs because there are two values carried in OpenArgs and it's a lot easier to just pull each out once and then use the variable name when I need it (which is a lot, actually).

The suggestion that there may be an error someplace actually makes a lot of sense.  I tried putting the value into two variables upfront, VigilTable and SaveVigilTable, then attempted to copy SaveVigilTable to VigilTable after loading the called form and got nothing.

Comment: I am getting an error from the called form but only on every odd (1, 3, 5, etc.) try: Invalid use of NULL, with the code that unpacks OpenArgs highlighted.

First time I call that form, I get that error.  I have to close both forms, reopen the first and then call the second and everything works fine.

Comment: But if I try to call it again after closing it, VigilTable is blank in the original form; I have to close it, reopen it and then call the second form; then it works.  (I had actually planned on posting a second question on that, as I thought it was a separate issue but maybe it isn't.

Meantime, I am going to try declaring that and a few other variables in the standard form as they are used pretty much everywhere in this project.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, without question, you close a form, the the code, variables and values for that form will go away. So, if you need a true global var that persists - you have to declare as public in a standard code module - outside of the form. As such, then that var can be used inside a form, outside of a form, and used regardless if the form is open or not

Answer (score 1):

For a string variable, a more robust solution not influenced by any error, should be writing/reading in/from Registry. You can use the, let as say, variable (the string from Registry) from any workbook/application able to read Registry.

1. Declare some `Public` constants on top of a **standard module** (in the declarations area):

```
Public Const MyApp As String = "ExcelVar"
Public Const Sett As String = "Settings"
Public Const VigilTable As String = "VT"
```

2. Then, save the variable value from any module/form:

```
SaveSetting MyApp, Sett, VigilTable , "Spring2022" 'Save the string in Regisgtry
```

3. It can be read in the next way:

```
Dim myVal as String

myVal = GetSetting(MyApp, Sett, VigilTable , "No value") 'read the Registry
 If myVal = "No value" Then MsgBox "Nothing recorded in Registry, yet": Exit Sub  
Debug.print myVal
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this proved not to be the the answer at all.

It was suggested that I declare my variables as constants in the Standard module but I declared them as variables.  It appeared at first to work, at least through one entire session, then it ceased to work and I don't know why.

If I declare as constants instead, will I still be able to change them at-will?  That matters because I re-use them with different values at different times.

I didn't do constants but declaring VigilName in the Standard module and deleting all other declarations of it fixed both problems.

While I was at it I declared several other variables that are as generally used and deleted all other declarations of them as well so that at least they'll be consistently used throughout (probably save me some troubleshooting later.

Thanks to all!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).